# Container should communicate to host network, but does not

Tags: docker

I have a two HTTP servers on my host machine; one listening on `8080`, the other listening on `8081`. The `8080` is a webapp, and the `8081` is an API.

I also have a Docker container that should connect to the webapp on `8080` using an automated tool, and that webapp should make HTTP requests to the API that's on `8081`.

Here is a visual representation of what I want:

```
Host machine HTTP 8080
          ⇩            ⇖
          ⇧              Docker container 
Host machine HTTP 8081
```

The problem I'm having is that the Docker container cannot connect to the website on the host machines `8080`. I'm not sure why, because I set the `--network=host` flag, so shouldn't it be using the host machines network?

This is my Docker image:

```
## Redacted irrelevant stuff...

EXPOSE 8080 8081
```

This is how run the container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 --network=host --name=app app
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Hi, with a -p publish option you don't have to expose port (in my opinion), and try to delete your --network option. -p option should works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two services running directly on the machine and you want to deploy a Docker container that should connect to one of those services.
In that case, you shouldn't map those port to the container and you shouldn't expose those ports in the Dockerfile as those ports are not for the container.

1. Remove the `Expose` ports from the Dockerfile
2. Start the container using `docker run -d --network=host --name=app app`. The container should be able to access the services using `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This doesn't seem to solve the problem, my automated tool still says it can't find a host at `http://localhost:8080`. Going to debug further...

Comment: Wait, never mind, I have a typo somewhere... one sec may accept your answer in a moment.

Comment: Thanks. Even though technically my original solution worked (I just had a typo in my webserver that was not being logged), I still accept this answer because it showed some redundancies and needless pieces I had, which is always nice. :)